# What is required to use Angular 2 within IE9?

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-9

I've been trying to create an Angular 2 application (using the get started guide) as a template but while it works really well in Chrome I'm struggling to get it working in IE9!

Basically the app is failing while loading/running boot/js with the following error reported to the developer console..

LOG: Error: Object doesn't support this action

Does anyone have any recommendations or suggestions - even better - a demo that actually works in IE9?

The start of my index.html looks like the following...

```
<head>
<title ng-bind="title">xxx</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
<base href="/">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" />

</body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.4.1/es5-sham.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.34.1/es6-sham.min.js"></script>
<script src="/app/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/systemjs/systemjs/0.19.6/dist/system.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/angular2.dev.js"></script>

<script>
    System.config({
    packages: {        
      app: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
  System.import('app/boot')
        .then(null, function(err){
            console.log(err);
        });
</script>
```

With the Angular code following https://angular.io/guide/quickstart to the letter!

Update 1:
With a bit more testing (mostly in newer IE browsers) I am experiancing the same issue but seeing more details..

```
    TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'keys'
   at Anonymous function (http://localhost:5000/app/angular2.dev.js:783:5)
   at Anonymous function (http://localhost:5000/app/angular2.dev.js:781:3)
   at linkDynamicModule (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.16/system.src.js:3130:5)
   at getModule (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.16/system.src.js:3098:9)
   at Anonymous function (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.16/system.src.js:3134:9)
   at Anonymous function (http://localhost:5000/app/angular2.dev.js:10795:3)
   at linkDynamicModule (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.16/system.src.js:3130:5)
   at getModule (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.16/system.src.js:3098:9)
   at Anonymous function (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.16/system.src.js:3134:9)
   at Anonymous function (http://localhost:5000/app/angular2.dev.js:12011:3)
```

The index.html currently looks like..

```
<head>
<title ng-bind="title">xxx</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
<base href="/">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.4.1/es5-sham.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.34.1/es6-sham.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>

<script src="/app/reflect.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.16/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.16/system-polyfills.src.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/Rx.js"></script>
<!--<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/angular2.dev.js"></script>-->
<script src="/app/angular2.dev.js"></script>



<script src="/app/shims_for_IE.js"></script>


<script>
    System.config({
    packages: {        
      app: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
  System.import('app/boot')
        .then(function(){
        }, function(err){
            console.log(err.stack);
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure you're actually running the browser in IE9 mode?

Comment: Well.... I'm using browser stack :)

Comment: Have you traced the error down to a particular piece of code that can be debugged?

Comment: Hit F12 and check if IE runs in IE9 or emulation mode

Comment: It's a fair comment.. but Jo public doesn't care about if their browser is capable or not!

Just that the app they want to use works

Comment: It's a full fat IE9 browser no emulation, no faking :)

Comment: Angular 2 supports IE9, so asking for help with an Ie9 support issue is legitimate in this case. however, i think you need to include far more information in your question, it's extremely broad at this point. For all we know it could be a problem introduced by your code, not the angular core.

Comment: @KevinB fair point -- I've updated the question with the start of my index.html but the rest of the code really is just following the get started guide... nothing special at this point, so didn't pollute the question!

Comment: but where does the error occur?

Comment: Honestly.. I'm not sure!

The only thing spat out in the console is from the console.log statement in the system import promise..

LOG: Error: Object doesn't support this action
 Error loading http://localhost:5000/app/boot.js

Comment: Log the trace. `console.log(err.stack)` This should point you to a particular file and line number.

Comment: You would think so.. but it's not being populated!

I've added some comments to the boot.js generated from the boot.ts file and while it displays the console log statement before System.register(..) it's not reaching the comments inside..

console.log(System.register) shows the function is there..

I've set a breakpoint and going to debug into it and see where it fails!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100648/discussion-between-andycwk-and-kevin-b).

Answer (score 5):

Fix for Angular2 RC4 IE9:

- Include script:

`<script src="https://npmcdn.com/angular2@2.0.0beta.17/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>`

- Change routing method to '#'

`import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
...
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    ...,
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }
]);`

- Don't use browser history to navigate:

`window.history.back(); //BAD`

Comment: nice :)  I'll give it a shot when I get a moment later in the week :)

Answer (score 2):

So, after several hours of hair pulling, a conversation on here with @kevinB (thanks) and eventually raising a ticket https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6479#issuecomment-171582759

it turns out it was human error!!

I had copy/pasted the wrong links from the cloudflare CDN site, referencing es6-sh**a**m.js instead of es6-sh**i**m.js

Such a small typo - but with massive consequences!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the node package [ie-shim](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ie-shim), install on the command line using `npm install ie-shim --save`

Maybe reference in your `ployfills.ts` to import library on build:

```
import 'ie-shim';
```

Probably a good idea to include it before zone.js import.

Answer (score 0):

Add this lines of code just after your `<head>` in index.html

Note: Order must be same

`<script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Angular 2.4.0 and was able to get it to work with IE9 with the following pollyfills:

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
```

I had expected the core-js shim to provide full support for IE9 too but it was still missing some functions. Adding shims_for_IE seemed to work well.

With regards to routing in IE9, the following answer was helpful:
[How to bootstrap with HashLocationStrategy in Angular 2 RC5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38964450/how-to-bootstrap-with-hashlocationstrategy-in-angular-2-rc5)