# Angular 2 support IE9?

Tags: internet-explorer-9, angular

Does anyone knows what magics need to do for running application in IE9 browser?
Because even quick start application from angular.io doesn't run there. If it possible show source code of index.html and package.json files or other necessary things.

Comment: Are you running it on IE9 or some other IE emulating IE9? 'Cause they may seem the same, but they aren't at all.

Comment: I use virtual machines from https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/windows/

Comment: See also https://github.com/angular/angular/search?q=ie9&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have a typo similar to [What is required to use Angular 2 within IE9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34775684/what-is-required-to-use-angular-2-within-ie9)

For me the boilerplate from https://github.com/mschwarzmueller/angular-2-beta-boilerplate which is based on that quick start application worked also with IE9 (version on the machine I tested with is 9.0.8112.16421).