# How to bootstrap with HashLocationStrategy in Angular 2 RC5

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm upgrading from Angular 2 RC4 to RC5

Here's my current main.ts

```
import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';
import {bootstrap}    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {AppComponent} from './app/app.component';
import {AppRoutes} from './app/app.routes';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { XHRBackend } from '@angular/http';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';
import { LocationStrategy,
         HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import {disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms} from '@angular/forms';
import {provide} from '@angular/core';

enableProdMode();
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  disableDeprecatedForms(),
  provideForms(),
  provideRouter(AppRoutes)
  ,HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})

])
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Here's my updated main.ts

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {AppModule} from './app/app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Here's the app.modules.ts

```
import { NgModule }       from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }    from '@angular/forms';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { routing } from './app.routes';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        routing
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

How can I use HashLocationStrategy with RC5? How can I enable Production mode?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You may use below,

**routing**

```
 export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true });
```

for enabling production mode, before loading root `NgModule`,

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

if (<condition to enable production mode>) {
   enableProdMode();
}
```

Read more about [LocationStrategy and browser URL styles here](https://angular.io/guide/router#appendix-locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles).

Comment: Thanks. Was this documented somewhere on github or on angular.io??

Comment: you may read about it [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#browser-url-styles)

Comment: If you want your website to be indexed by google **don't use hash**! (https://www.seroundtable.com/google-no-hashtags-in-urls-26537.html)