# Angular 2 router urls without hash causes problems on refresh

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

Im creating an angular 2 app( previous angular 1 developer )
and im finding it difficult to get angular 2 urls to work with my server.

Basically, angular 2 doesnt use #, which means when an in-app route changes from 
"/" to pages/1, then angular loads pages/1 component and all data using ajax, and displays the pages. It works nice. However, when user refreshes the pages, then ...the page wont work.

Is there something i can do/configure, to make the angular app to reload the page at "/", but provide some hidden parameters to server like "pages/1" so that after page gets reloaded at "/", angular would know that user wanted to go to "pages/1" and do the redirect.

Comment: You need to enable Hashlocation so that angular router understands # based URL's see this [How to bootstrap with HashLocationStrategy in Angular 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38964450/how-to-bootstrap-with-hashlocationstrategy-in-angular-2-rc5/38964658#38964658), also you can read more about it [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#browser-url-styles). Hope this helps!!

Comment: The answer from the duplicate question doesn't cover apache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can switch to using hash:

```
imports: [
    /* ... */
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: true })
]
```

To support no-hash urls, the server must be configured to respond with the same index.html file for any requested url.

Comment: If you want your website to be indexed by google **don't use hash**! (https://www.seroundtable.com/google-no-hashtags-in-urls-26537.html)