# Angular 4 - setting the url on website to display the index.htm/l

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm building an app.
the app eventually will be in sub domain.
when i upload the dist file to the sub domain
everything going well but the url shows without the suffix 'index.html'
i.e domain.com/app/folder/ 
and i need it to be the full path - 
domain.com/app/folder/index.html 
(in my case index.htm)

Does anyone knows how to configure it?

Comment: I guess you want `RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true });` I don't think `index.html` is shown with `PathLocationStrategy` See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38964450/how-to-bootstrap-with-hashlocationstrategy-in-angular-2-rc5

Comment: Why do you "need" this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the `base href` in your `index.html`, and the angular router will recognize it, so `<base href="example.com/folder/index.htm">` worths trying.

Comment: Is there a way to make the address without the slash in the end? the page now when you insert the url 'example.com/folder/index.htm' updated immediately to 'example.com/folder/index.htm/' --> with slash –

Comment: Following because I have the same problem. And I also get an error that Angular cant match any routes with the segment `index.html`.

Comment: Plus this method seems not to work in production. :/